# Is it possible to pass more than 2 private members to a class?

Tags: c++, qt, private

I have a problem while compiling in my Qt code. I don't know why I can't pass more than two private members to a class. Here's the code:

In the header file(named wind.h)

```
 #ifndef WIND_H
 #define WIND_H

 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QWidget>
 #include <QPushButton>

class second : public QWidget
{
    public:
        second();

    private:
        QPushButton *bout1;
        QPushButton *bout2;
        QPushButton *bout3;
};
#endif // WIND_H
```

In the wind.cpp file

```
  #include "wind.h"

 second::second() :QWidget()
 {
    setFixedSize(700, 150);
    bout1 = new QPushButton("button1", this);
    bout2 = new QPushButton("button2", this);
    bout3 = new QPushButton("button3", this);
}
```

And the main.cpp be like

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "wind.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    second sec;
    sec.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Actually,this code doesn"t compile and runs the debug,there is even a error in the debug but if I put this line in comment it works :

```
  //bout3 = new QPushButton("button3", this);
```

So why isn't it working when I pass more than 2 private members ? And how could I fix it ?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: This sounds more like a C++ problem than a Qt one. Please make the example more self-contained if possible, and also more minimal. Anyway, "doesn't work" is about the least useful description for anyone trying to help.

Comment: uncomment that line and comment another, still working?

Comment: Raydel Miranda It is still working,as I said I doesn"t seem to accept more than 2 private members , Chris,Okay I'll make it more minimal ;)

Comment: Note that by self-contained, I mean something I could just paste into an online compiler. No Qt if your problem still happens without any Qt.

Comment: Is the problem that you cannot see the third button ?  Or that nothing at all appears ??  Or that the programm crashes ???  And what if you add bout3->SetFont/SetCursor and Move ?

Comment: Christophe,the program crashes ;)

Comment: Kuba Ober I mean by doesn't work that it stops compiling and runs the debug,and it shows a message like:failed in debug

Comment: Can you post the call stack at the crash location?

Comment: Wait does it compile or doesn't it? If it doesn't compile, then how can it crash? And more importantly: if it doesn't compile, what's the error message you get from the compiler?

Comment: To show multiple widgets you should add them to a layout, and use that layout on the main window (widget).

Comment: I use Qt with french langage,here the error message anyway Démarrage de C:\Qt\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\Test.exe...
Le programme s'est terminé subitement.
C:\Qt\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\Test.exe a planté which means program stopped,and the debug failed

Comment: Clean, run qmake, and rebuild and run is useful ? I hope you have nothing in your project in addition than what you posted above.

Comment: Kknd Is it the only way to show 3 widgets ? I mean that I wanted to keep may main.cpp minimal and set all widgets int the two other files

Comment: Martin,I have followed those steps,still the same thing,what I don't understand is that It doesn't want to take more than 2 widgets defined in my .h file ,is there a rule in c++ or anything that prohibits passing more than 2 private members ?

Comment: No there is no such rule, it's not the problem at all. You have a problem probably with your project or something else. I don't see any mistake in your code. Create a whole new project and follow what Kknd said about widgets/layout.

Comment: As I've said once, I'll say again: **your code, as shown, compiles, runs and doesn't crash**. I've put it into a continuous integration system that compiles and tests on a dozen disfferent configurations, with Qt versions including 4.8, 5.0, 5.1 and 5.2. Your problem is elsewhere. The code that you've posted is OK. It's not the nicest code out there, but it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as shown. For reference, here's a single file example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

class Second : public QWidget
{
public:
   Second();

private:
   QPushButton *bout1;
   QPushButton *bout2;
   QPushButton *bout3;
};

Second::Second() : QWidget()
{
   setFixedSize(700, 150);
   bout1 = new QPushButton("button1", this);
   bout2 = new QPushButton("button2", this);
   bout3 = new QPushButton("button3", this);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   Second sec;
   sec.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```

You don't need to list the base class constructor explicitly on the initializer list if you don't pass it any parameters. You also don't need to allocate anything on the heap explicitly. So, this is in a little better style:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

class Second : public QWidget
{
   QPushButton bout1, bout2, bout3;
public:
   Second();
};

Second::Second() :
   bout1("button1", this),
   bout2("button2", this),
   bout3("button3", this)
{
   setFixedSize(700, 150);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   Second sec;
   sec.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```